# Any idea on auto clean coffee filter mechanism?

Tags: espresso-machine, coffee-machines, filter, paper-filter

Do you have any idea on how to design a filter for fine substances left over after the brewing process (e.g. ground coffee or tea) without human intervention? This filter will be used in a vending machine, so the auto cleaning process must be done with rotation, blowing, washing, etc.

Comment: Please be more detailed in your request. Coffee and tea are brewed in different ways, with the former typically involving pushing water through coffee and the latter typically involving submerging tea in water, unless using a coffee brewing method like French press. Also, a popular design for this purpose is that of single use filters of disposable filtering media, like plastic or coated paper, which involve a per-use cost and are not environmentally friendly. What are the specific requirements of this project, and what is/are the method(s) used to brew?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly but here's what I thought: Maybe a strip of some sort stretched by two rollers. This would enable the use of a rotating cleaning brush. For the material of the strip I'm not sure..

Hope it's of any help..